# CLS sheet has no \em, \emph, or \textit, yet I'm getting italix?

Tags: fonts, xetex

This is what I'm getting in the address line of my resume:

[image]

And yet, my code in the .tex file has no italix:

```
\address{\setmainfont{times.ttf} (111)~$\cdot$~111~$\cdot$~1111 \\ email@uni.edu \\ github.com/First-Middle-Last }
```

And the \address command (and its styling \printaddress command) have no italix in it:

```
\def \addressSep {\bullet} % Set default address separator to a diamond

% One, two or three address lines can be specified 
\let \@addressone \relax
\let \@addresstwo \relax
\let \@addressthree \relax

% \address command can be used to set the first, second, and third address (last 2 optional)
\def \address #1{
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{
    \def \@addresstwo {#1}
  }{
  \@ifundefined{@addressthree}{
  \def \@addressthree {#1}
  }{
     \def \@addressone {#1}
  }}
}

% \printaddress is used to style an address line (given as input)
\def \printaddress #1{
  \begingroup
    \def \\ {\addressSep\ }
    \centerline{#1}
  \endgroup
  \par
  \addressskip
}
```

Why is my address line italicized, and how can I make it normal? I have already tried \normalfont.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code features the following instruction:

```
\def \addressSep {\bullet}
```

`\bullet` is a math-mode command. You must have been getting (and apparently blithely ignoring) warning messages about a command occurring outside math mode. In consequence, stuff is being typeset in math mode, *not* in text italics. Just because LaTeX didn't crash outright doesn't mean that it's ok to ignore error messages.

Moral of the story? Don't ignore warning and error messages, and -- in the definition of `\addressSep` -- use `\textbullet`, not `\bullet`.